# How to prepare poured concrete wall for adhesion

Tags: concrete, walls

I am considering the application of an artificial stone wall veneer onto a poured concrete wall. The wall is flat with no protrusions or other which might aid in adhesion. I do not know if any release agents were added to the forms when the wall was poured. Age of the wall is less than 15 years.

What is the best method to prep the surface to get the best adhesion and is there a best mortar for use in this manner? I have done a lot of drywall and other concrete work, but nothing to do with block or mortar so this is somewhat of a new area for me. The wall is about 9 feet high and 15 feet long and flat with no corners with a concrete floor - all bare an never painted.

How should I prepare this surface and what should I use for mortar here? I want it to look as natural as possible so do not want to use any caulk like adhesives etc. if possible.  Any other tips I might find of use?

EDIT: This is an interior wall, thus no weathering and has never been painted or otherwise surface treated.

Answer (score 3):

If the wall is unpolished it already offers enough grip for any other concrete based adhesive.
Just make sure its dust free..dampen the concrete wall with a sponge.. let the water drip and sink into the wall and then use a normal adhesive recommended to be used stone veneer direct to the concrete

If it is polished concrete then you will need to grind slits into the concrete so that the concrete can adhere, also taking care to get the concrete into the prepared slits.

You do not need to use any other chemicals that i know off. done it plenty of times when applying plaster direct on concrete or slitted polished wall.. sticks forever.

Just make sure not use adhesive that dries super fast.. just a normal drying adhesive. Drying to fast can cause it the "glue" to shrink and pull away from the wall before it bonds properly.. that is why the wall should also be wet before application